# Full text of the 'Sri Mahalakshmi Dhyanam & Stotram'

Tags: devi, shloka, stotra, lakshmi, devi-bhagavata-purana

I recently came across a piece of paper in my parents' home that is entitled '*Sri Mahalaxmi Dhyanamum Stotramum*'. (It is written in English)

The first line is:

> 'sahasratala padmasta karnikaa vaasineem paraam, saratpaarvana kodeentu prapaamusteekaraam paraam.'

I searched the name of the sloka online, and there were some videos, but all of those were different and not the sloka that I am looking for.

But there seems to be more text to the sloka...does anyone have the full text to it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Stotra is **Indra Krita Lakshmi Stotram**, from the [**Devi Bhagavata Purana, 9th Canto, Chapter 42**](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/db/bk09ch42.htm), and was chanted by Lord Indra to Goddess Mahalakshmi.

The original Devi Bhagavata chapter seems to have lots of additional prayers made by Indra to Goddess Mahalakshmi along with the offering of the sixteen Upacharas, before the commencement of the actual stotra.

The **complete Sanskrit text of Devi Bhagavata 9.42** (containing the Dhyana Shloka, Shodasha Upachara Puja and Mahalakshmi Stotra) can be found on **[pages 683-686 of this pdf of the Sanskrit version of the Purana](https://archive.org/details/SrimadDeviBhagavatamSanskrit/page/n685/mode/1up)**.

The Sanskrit text of **only the stotra** can be found on **[this page](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/indralaxmistotra.itx)**.

As found on the sanskritdocuments website, the actual Stotra seems to be Devi Bhagavata 9.42.8-10.5 and 9.42.51-75.

This stotra comes in connection with the legend of Samudra Mathana. According to the story, when Sage Durvasa gifted a garland (given to him by Lord Vishnu and Devi Mahalakshmi) to Lord Indra, Indra disrespected the gift, and thereby was cursed by Durvasa to lose all prosperity and Grace of Mahalakshmi. In order to regain their prosperity, the Devas along with the asuras churned the ocean of milk and obtained, among other treasures, Amrita and Goddess Mahalakshmi's blessings.

After the churning completed successfully, Indra worshipped Lord Vishnu, and then offered his prayers to Mahalakshmi through this Stotra.

For the benefit of the reader, I'm quoting the first shloka from the question, along with the translation by Swami Vijnanananda.

> **dhyAnam**
>
> sahasradalapadmasthakarNikAvAsinIM parAm |
> sharatpArvaNakoTInduprabhAmuShTikarAM parAm || 1||
> svatejasA prajvalantIM sukhadRRishyAM manoharAm |
> prataptakA~nchananibhashobhAM mUrtimatIM satIm || 2||
> ratnabhUShaNabhUShADhyAM shobhitAM pItavAsasA |
> IShaddhAsyaprasannAsyAM shashvatsusthirayauvanAm |
> sarvasampatpradAtrIM cha mahAlakShmIM bhaje shubhAm || 3||

Translation:

> “O Mother! Thou residest on the thousand-petalled lotus. The beauty of Thy face excels the beauty of koti autumnal Full Moons. Thou art shining with Thy own splendour. Thou art very beautiful and lovely; Thy colour is like the burnished gold; Thou art with form, chaste, ornamented all over with jewel ornaments; Thou art wearing the yellow cloth and look! What beauty is coming out of it! Always a sweet smile reigns on Thy lips. Thy beauty is constant; Thou art the bestower of prosperity to all. O Mahâ Laksmî! I meditate on Thee.”

Answer (score 4):

This sloka is in the [Stotramālay](https://www.amazon.in/Stothjramala-Kalaimagal-Traders/dp/B09BTGZCH1) book, although I'm not quite sure where it came from.

It is part of a longer text, I'm fairly certain, but the 'Dhyanam' part is just the following. I have attached a photo of it here, and also transcribed and transliterated it.

[image]

Tamil Version:

> (ஸகல ஸம்பத்துகளையும், மங்களத்தையும் ஆலிக்கக்கூடீய ஸ்தோத்ரம்)
>
> ஸஹஸ்ரதள பத்மஸ்த கர்ணிகா வாஸினீம் பராம் |
> சரத்பார்வண கோடீந்து ப்ரபாமுஷ்டிகராம பராம் ||
>
> ஸ்வதேஜஸா ப்ரஜ்வலந்தீம் ஸுகத்ருச்யாம் மனோஹராம் |
> ப்ரத்பத காஞ்சனிப சோபாம் மூர்திமதீம் ஸதீம் ||
>
> ரத்னபூஷண புஷாட்யாம் சோபிதாம் பீதவாஸஸாம் |
> ஈஷத்தாஸ்ய ப்ரஸன்னாஸ்யம் சச்வசத்ஸுஸ்திரயேளவனாம் ||
>
> சர்வஸம்பத் ப்ரதாத்ரீம் ச மஹாலக்ஷ்மீம் பஜேசுபாம் |||

English Version:

> (Sakala sampattukaḷaiyum, maṅkaḷattaiyum ālikkakkūṭīya stōtram)
>
> sahasrataḷa patmasta karṇikā vāsiṉīm parām |
> caratpārvaṇa kōṭīntu prapāmuṣṭikarāma parām ||
>
> svatējasā prajvalantīm sukatrucyām maṉōharām |
> pratpata kāñcaṉipa cōpām mūrtimatīm satīm ||
>
> ratṉapūṣaṇa puṣāṭyām cōpitām pītavāsasām |
> īṣattāsya prasaṉṉāsyam cacvacatsustirayēḷavaṉām ||
> carvasampat pratātrīm ca mahālakṣmīm pajēcupām |||